# What does 'for' mean in 1 Corinthians 15:3?

Tags: 1-corinthians, paul, sin, atonement

> **1 Corinthians 15:3** For what I received I passed on to you as of first importance: that Christ died **for** our sins according to the Scriptures,

Some possibilities I can think of:

- 'directly because of': we sinned by putting him to death.
- 'indirectly because of': humanity's sinful state resulted in Jesus being killed.
- 'to correct': to make us stop sinning.
- 'to forgive': to allow God to forgive us.

I'm sure there are many other possibilities. Is there any way to narrow down the possibilities linguistically?

Bonus question: was Paul being deliberately cryptic with ambiguous phrasing or would he expect his readers to know what he meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

1 Corinthians 15:3

> For what I received I passed on to you as of first importance: that Christ died **for our sins** according to the Scriptures,

for
ὑπὲρ (hyper)
Preposition
Strong's 5228: **Genitive: in behalf of**; acc: above.

our
ἡμῶν (hēmōn)
Personal / Possessive Pronoun - **Genitive** 1st Person Plural
Strong's 1473: I, the first-person pronoun. A primary pronoun of the first person I.

Literally, it says:

> Christ died on behalf of our sins

It is more than just because of our sins. Paul expressed the same idea in Galatians 1:4

> who gave himself **for our sins** to rescue us from the present evil age, according to the will of our God and Father,

A somewhat different idea is expressed in Romans 5:8

> But God demonstrates his own love for us in this: While we were still sinners, Christ died **for us** [on behalf of us].

Christ died not just because of our sins. He died on behalf of us and our sins.
He was a sin offering for the forgiveness of sins on our behalf.